# getEventsForDay() formatting issues with datepicker return value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Calendar API to pull up some events based on datepicker output. The issue that i'm facing with my AppScript is formatting properly the value that i get from the datepicker that will serve as input for the getEventsForDay() function.

```
function testing(){
 var z = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("X")[0];
 var date = new Date('2016-10-12');
 var dateformatted =Utilities.formatDate(date), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
 var a = z.getEventsForDay(dateformatted, {search: 'OOO'});
```

The output of a into this scenario is a empty object - which is expected because this formatting is not working at all. (i've read 1000 posts that this should work).

For context as well, i have one working example with today's date, which it works fine becase the input is a new Date(). Here you go:

```
 var datetoday = new Date();  
 var b = z.getEventsForDay(datetoday, {search: 'OOO'});
```

Any ideas on what i'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `new Date()` returns the Date object in UTC and not the local timezone, you may be querying the wrong day and hence the empty object if the other day does not have any events.

You can covert the date to the current timezone like

```
date.setTime(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000)
```

This should return the date in the local timezone and you will get the events for the correct day.

Hope it helps

Comment: Solve like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Actually there's an issue with this solution: It works only for the today's date. If you set a date for the future, it will keep returning the today's date. At least from the test i've did here so far.

Comment: I realize just now that if i add the entry as new Date('July 1, 1999') it works. But the whole issue is then how to convert to this format from my date picker that output the results as "YYYY-MM-DD"

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes and now this works on the App Script:

```
 var t = "2016-10-01";
 var q = t.replace(/-/g,"/");
 var a = new Date(q);
 a.setTime(a.getTime() + a.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000)
 var w = z.getEventsForDay(a, {search: 'OOO'}); 
 Logger.log(a);
 Logger.log(w);
```